# How to display image from mysql database to full calendar using zend

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, fullcalendar

Hi I want to display a photo in events fullcalendar 
I'm using zend framework i put the calendar in my view **match.html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        editable: true,
        events: "<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/application/models/events.php"

    });

});
```

`enter code here`